# Calling SNS services from Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I need help with Java AWS-Lambda.

I am working on Lambda to update the database. There is cloudwatch event trigger and invoke Lambda for an update database based on some criteria. I want to send notification as soon as DB update. I want to invoke SNS services from Lambda.

I am using SNS account which running with multi-factor authentication. Please suggest how to create/setup lambda to send SNS.

Note: I am **not looking at "how to trigger Lambda from SNS**". I am looking at ***how to send SNS from the Lambda function IN JAVA***.

Comment: What part of the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-to-topic.html#publish-message-to-topic-aws-java) are unclear?  Sending from a Lambda is no different than any other place.

Comment: Can you please check the answer below and let me know if it works for you or not

Comment: Its working but I need to check how to create AmazonSNS Object. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is a simple way of publishing a message to an SNS topic using [aws java sdk.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-to-topic.html#publish-message-to-topic-aws-java)
- To publish message with attributes use this java code sample [Publish a Message with Attributes to an Amazon SNS Topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-with-attributes.html#publish-message-with-attributes-aws-java)
- You basically have to use the same code in your lambda handler.
- you need to grant your Lambda IAM role permissions to publish to your SNS topic using appropriate IAM Policy.

```
// Publish a message to an Amazon SNS topic.
final String msg = "If you receive this message, publishing a message to an Amazon SNS topic works.";
final PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(topicArn, msg);
final PublishResult publishResponse = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);

// Print the MessageId of the message.
System.out.println("MessageId: " + publishResponse.getMessageId());
```

- This is how i have done in my project created a helperservice and used in my lambdahandler.

```
    // my lambda handler
    public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(ApiGatewayRequest request, Context context) {

        try {
            // call to the helperservice
            PublishResult publishResult = helperService.publishMessage("Message to be published to sns topic");
            //return response 
            return buildResponse(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            this.logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return buildResponse(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    // HerperService class class
    public class HelperService {

    private final AmazonSNS snsClient;
    private final Configuration config;

    @Inject
    public HelperService(
            AmazonSNS snsClient,
            Configuration config,
    ) {
        this.snsClient = snsClient;
        this.config = config;
    }

    public PublishResult publishMessage(String message) {
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(config.getAuditSNSTopicARN(), message);
        return snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to create HelperService object ?? It's required 2 params, please share elements. Please don't share your private credentials.

Comment: @VivekMishra this is just one way of implementation in my case the `HelperService` uses a config. You don't need to use it. So don't get confused you just need the `publishMessage` method.